# Migrating google cloud App Engine Standard zones

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to deploy an a flask application entirely in the free tier of GCP.

I have deployed it on App Engine Standard in the us-west2 zone, and am now getting charged for cloud storage. [It turns out cloud storage only has a free tier in the us-east1, us-west1, and us-central1 zones.](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier)

I cannot seem to figure out how to migrate or redeploy my app in the us-west1 region. There is plenty of documentation around migrating zones, but none of it seems to apply to App Engine Standard. Does GCP allow migration of App Engine Standard apps, and if so, how can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indeed, is not possible to move the region of an app once is set, the documentation states that:

`You cannot change an app's region after you set it.` [App Engine Locations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations).

But, as well states that:

**Cloud Storage Location**
When you create an app, App Engine creates a default bucket in Cloud Storage. Generally, the location of this bucket is the region matching the location of your App Engine app.

regarding buckets, seems that is possible to rename it and move it to a different region, so you can give it a try moving your bucket back to free tier and see if that help with your billing, otherwise, as stated in the previous response, you will have to recreate your app basically from scratch.

[Moving and renaming buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets)

When you create a bucket, you permanently define its name, its geographic location, and the project it is part of. However, you can effectively move or rename your bucket:

--If there is no data in your old bucket, delete the bucket and create another bucket with a new name, in a new location, or in a new project.

-- If you have data in your old bucket, create a new bucket with the desired name, location, and/or project, copy data from the old bucket to the new bucket, and delete the old bucket and its contents. The steps below describe this process.

- If you want your new bucket to have the same name as your old bucket, you must temporarily move your data to a bucket with a different name. This lets you delete the original bucket so that you can reuse the bucket name.
- **Moving data between locations incurs network usage costs. In addition, moving data between buckets may incur retrieval and early deletion fees**, if the data being moved are Nearline Storage, Coldline Storage, or Archive Storage objects.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not zone, but region in the Google Cloud semantic. But anyway, I understood.

And you can't change the region of a App Engine. You need to delete your project and to create it again. Or to create a new project and set the correct region from the init. Don't forget to save your data is you delete your project.

*App Engine is a 13+ years old app and Google Cloud didn't think about this migration from the beginning. It's the weight of the legacy!*